# Understanding BSON Notation

Tags: bson

I was trying to understand **BSON Notations** from the site [BSON Site](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification). However I was unable to understand the reason behind the correlations.

I also referred the following questions, but am not convinced because of the following reasons.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855681/better-explanation-of-bson-spec-examples) : Not familiar with **ruby** implementations

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554325/why-is-it-called-bson/3554355#3554355) : I understood the byte allocation. But unsure about the notations.

I would like to know **how the bson object is formed for the following examples** in [BSON Site](http://bsonspec.org/#/specificaiton)

**1.{"hello": "world"}

  2.{"BSON": ["awesome", 5.05, 1986]}**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**{"hello": "world"}**

```
\x16\x00\x00\x00
  \x02 hello\x00 \x06\x00\x00\x00 world\x00
\x00
```

(overall: 22 bytes)

The first four bytes contain the overall length as a 32-bit little-endian integer.

`\x16\x00\x00\x00` => That's 22 in decimal.

Now comes the first element. The first byte gives the type of data.

`\x02` => That's a UTF-8 string.

Then comes the name of the first element, as a null-terminated string.

`hello\x00`

Next comes the data of the element in the previously given type, in this case a string.
For scannability (so you can quickly skip when you don't need them), strings start with their length, and are null-terminated.

`\x06\x00\x00\x00` => That's length 6.

`world\x00`

Now would come subsequent elements, if there were any. The whole thing is terminated with a null byte.

`\x00`

---

**{"BSON": ["awesome", 5.05, 1986]}**

```
\x31\x00\x00\x00
  \x04 BSON\x00 \x26\x00\x00\x00
                  \x02 0\x00 \x08\x00\x00\x00 awesome\x00
                  \x01 1\x00 \x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x14\x40
                  \x10 2\x00 \xc2\x07\x00\x00
                \x00
\x00
```

(overall: 49 bytes, array: 38 bytes)

The first four bytes contain the overall length as a 32-bit little-endian integer.

`\x31\x00\x00\x00` => That's 49 in decimal.

Now comes the first element. The first byte gives the type of data.

`\x04` => That's an array.

Then comes the name of the first element, as a null-terminated string.

`BSON\x00`

Next comes the data of the element in the previously given type, in this case an array.

*[Quote: "The document for an array is a normal BSON document with
integers for the keys, starting with 0 (..)"]*

For scannability and because they form document in their own right, arrays start with their length, and are null-terminated.

`\x26\x00\x00\x00` => That's 38 in decimal.

Now comes the first element of the array. The first byte gives the type of data.

`\x02` => That's a UTF-8 string.

Then comes the name of the first element of the array, null-terminated.

`0\x00` => That's key 0.

Next comes the data of the element in the previously given type, in this case a string.
Strings start with their length, and are null-terminated.

`\x08\x00\x00\x00` => length 8

`awesome\x00`

Now comes the second element of the array. The first byte gives the type of data.

`\x01` => That's a double floating point number.

Then comes the name of the second element of the array, null-terminated.

`1\x00` => That's key 1.

Next comes the data of the element in the previously given type, in this case a double floating point number.

`\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x14\x40` => That's 5.5.

Now comes the third element of the array. The first byte gives the type of data.

`\x10` => That's a 32-bit integer.

Then comes the name of the third element of the array, null-terminated.

`2\x00` => That's key 2.

Next comes the data of the element in the previously given type, in this case a 32-bit integer.

`\xc2\x07\x00\x00` => That's 1986.

The array is terminated with a null byte.

`\x00`

The whole thing is terminated with a null byte.

`\x00`

Comment: Thanks @NicolasKaiser..Regarding little endian characters,                                            http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/

Comment: Can you explain "`\xc2\x07\x00\x00` => That's 1986."?